# General Vs Technician Call Sign?

Tags: united-states, callsign

Is there a distinction between a call sign for a General vs. Technician?

I recently upgraded to general, I am curious about changing call sign to reflect license upgrade?

Comment: am I right to assume this is a question about US regulations?

Comment: Yes US Regulations  Thx

Answer (score 6):

According to the [FCC's Amateur Call Sign Systems page](https://www.fcc.gov/amateur-call-sign-systems), Technician and General class operators are in the same group for call signs, so your call sign has a prefix of K, N, or W with a three-letter suffix, or a KL, NL, WL, NP, WP, KH, NH, or WH prefix with a two-letter suffix.  Because you've upgraded your license but are in the same call sign group, you're not entitled to any call sign format that you weren't already entitled to.

If you want a shorter call sign, you could always apply for a 1x3 license that isn't in current use through the "vanity" system.  Or you could study up for the Extra class license exam and pass it.  As an Extra-class licensee you could then request a new sequentially-issued license, which would be issued from the Extra call sign group, or apply for a "vanity" call sign from the Extra call sign group.